# Android - Loading language list on list view (yiddish language only not loading properly)

Tags: android

Hi i've loaded language list on list view.

i've received language list from google api.

When loading english and tamil language , the list view loaded properly.

When i select tamil language i've received like below

```
language: en Name : ஆங்கிலம்
language: ta Name : தமிழ்
language: fr Name : பிரெஞ்சு
language: yi Name : இதிஷ்
```

When i select english language i've received like below

```
language: en Name : English
language: ta Name : Tamil    
language: fr Name : French    
language: yi Name : Yiddish
```

[image]

[image]

But when i select yiddish language, languages name align right side, and the listview item sometime shows and sometime hide when scrolling the listview.

I've received language like below,

```
language: en Name : ענגליש    
language: ta Name : טאַמיל    
language: fr Name : פֿראַנצויזיש    
language: yi Name : אידיש
```

[image]

[image]

What is the problem , why yiddish language hide when scrolling. how to solve this?

Comment: Please check your adapter.It may occured due to scrolling listview.

Comment: set cacheColorHint of the listview as android:color/transparent

Answer (score 0):

Hebrew is written right to left, similar to Arabic. 
 [Hebrew Writing System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hebrew#Writing_system)